# Ajax Content disappear with page refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, onclick

I have a div element and onClick I am loading content using ajax, but after refresh the loaded content disappears.

Just want to keep the content there after page refresh.

Any solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax Content is persistent till the point you refresh the page, if you want to retain the values , you have two choices 1) Preload the content on server side and present the page to user, 2) as soon as page load is over, trigger the ajax command to load the ajax data that was presented earlier

Comment: I understand trigger is required , but I am not getting they way to keep the status of div element as clicked and trigger ajax based on that status. please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: You can store certain values as per the current state in some cookie and the use that data to reload values at refresh, a similar technique is being used by different controls, like if i have 5 tabs on a page and after page refresh i want to highlight the selected tab on previous page, we just pick the value from cookie for that

Comment: Actually I wanted to do this without using cookie , is there any solution for that ?

Comment: Yeah , you can append some reference data to url and then ensure that u return the reference data from server side and use that data for pick up , like for the tabs problem , on every page refresh , we used to send page2.jsp#ref=tab2 and after the page load we picked the value from url and used it

Comment: sure keep us posted, in case there is something that we might put on :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that once you send ajax request to page to be rendered store this date in session 
once you refresh the page you can render this partial from session if it was set before